# I want to save ReleaseDateYear to wma file

Tags: c#, wmp

I want to save ReleaseDateYear to wma file.

```
WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayerClass wmp = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayerClass();
WMPLib.IWMPMedia media = wmp.newMedia(targetSongpath);

global::music.mediainfo info = new global::music.mediainfo();

string Year = media.getItemInfo("Year");//value is empty

string ReleaseDateYearMonth = media.getItemInfo("ReleaseDateYearMonth");//1989/01/02 0:01:00

string AcquisitionTimeYearMonth = media.getItemInfo("AcquisitionTimeYearMonth");//value is empty

string ReleaseDateYear= media.getItemInfo("ReleaseDateYear");//32510

DateTime date = DateTime.FromOADate(Double.Parse(ReleaseDateYear));//1989/01/02

string AcquisitionTimeYear = media.getItemInfo("AcquisitionTimeYear");//value is empty

try {

    media.setItemInfo("ReleaseDateYearMonth", "1989/04/16");

    media.setItemInfo("ReleaseDateYear", "1989/04/16");

}
catch (Exception exception) {
    string error = exception.Message;
}
```

Code end normal.
But can't setinfo.
How can I set the datetime to wma file? Cheers